# Google closure compiler w/ ternaries: ERROR - inconsistent return type

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, ternary

So I have a helper namespace which I store helpful additions when developing JS. Now I plan to document them better and strengthen my JS with JsDoc and the help of Google Closure compiler. I got the lastest versions as of 2PM today. However I get errors with the when running the compiler on the following code:

```
var my.company.tool = {
    "isNumber": function( p_value )
    {
            return ( typeof(p_value) == "number" ) ? true : false;
    },
    /**
    * @static
    * @returns {Boolean} Indicative of an object.
    */
    "isObject": function( p_value )
    {
            return ( typeof(p_value) == "object" ) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

So on both return lines I get the compiler error "ERROR - inconsistent return type"

How do I use ternary operators like this with the Google closure compiler? And yes I've Googled, but I just keep getting irrelevant search results. For now I will remove the ternary but it would prefer to use them without errors:

So I updated my statements as suggested by "Tomasz Nurkiewicz", but I'm still getting the errors:
Changed made to code:

```
var my.company.tool = {
    "isNumber": function( p_value )
    {
            return typeof(p_value) == "number";
    },
    /**
    * @static
    * @returns {Boolean} Indicative of an object.
    */
    "isObject": function( p_value )
    {
            return typeof(p_value) == "object";
    }
}
```

Compiler output:

```
[pakeException]
    js/core/IHR.js:68: ERROR - inconsistent return type
    found   : boolean
    required: (Boolean|null)
            return typeof( p_value ) == "number";
                                     ^

    js/core/IHR.js:76: ERROR - inconsistent return type
    found   : boolean
    required: (Boolean|null)
            return ( typeof( p_value ) == "object" );
                                       ^

    2 error(s), 0 warning(s), 99.0% typed
```

Even when I try to set the type to {Boolean|null} I still get the errors. What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare your return type as `{boolean}` instead of `{Boolean}` because `{boolean}` refers to the primitive boolean type whereas `{Boolean}` refers to the wrapper `{Boolean}` type.

Comment: YES! That was it!. Thanks a lot. Where can I read up on things like that, also a reference of all the types the compiler supports?

Answer (score 2):

Will this help? In addition you have cleaner and more readable code...

```
var my.company.tool = {
    "isNumber": function( p_value )
    {
            return typeof(p_value) == "number";
    },
    "isObject": function( p_value )
    {
            return typeof(p_value) == "object";
    }
}
```

Comment: I like, I like, will try tomorrow when I get to work. Wow that was so obvious too.

Comment: Well no good, the code is cleaner and simpler, but I still get errors.